# Using vue as a view engine in Sails.js without the frontend

Tags: vue.js, sails.js

I'm setting up an email server using Sails.js (no frontend) and I need help with importing a vue file in my controller or setup the getRenderFn in View.js file to render my vue file.

I've tried a couple of things and nothing is working. The first thing I tried is changing the extension in my View.js file to vue but that's not enough. I have to write a rendering function as well and I don't know how to do that.

This led me to a second approach in my controller to import vue and use a library called [vue-server-renderer](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide). I'm returning the HTML and sending that through email. The problem is that I'm going to have several templates so my controller will be cluttered so I want to break it up to different files. I created a template.vue file and tried importing that in the controller but I'm getting a `script is undefined` error so I need a way to load the vue file in my controller.

```
module.exports = {
   send: function (req, res) {
     // change the type of body from obj to JSON so it's easy to parse
     let parsedBody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
     let emailSubj;
     let emailTemplate;
     const jsdom = require("jsdom");
     const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
     const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><div class="vue-target">Hello</div>`);

     const Vue = require('vue');
     const templateVue = require("../../views/template.vue");
     const Constructor = Vue.extend(templateVue);
     const getTemp = new Constructor({
         propsData: {
           body: parsedBody
         },
       render: h => h("../../views/template.vue"),
       }).$mount(dom.window.document.querySelector(".vue-target"));
     sails.log(getTemp);
      // create renderer
     const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer();
     let test;
     // Render the Vue instance to HTML
     renderer.renderToString(getTemp, (err, html) => {
       test = html;
       if (err) throw err;
       sails.log(html)
       // => <div data-server-rendered="true">Hello World</div>
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue this way

```
const Vue = require('vue');
     const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer();
     const app = new Vue({
       data: {
         title: 'this is a test title',
         Name: 'Name',
         Sender: 'Someone'
       },
       template: require('fs').readFileSync('./index.template.html', 'utf-8')
     });
     let sent;
     let context = {
       title: 'this is a test title',
       Name: 'Name',
       Sender: 'Someone'
     };
     renderer.renderToString(app, context, (err, html) => {
       if (err) {
         res.status(500).end('Internal Server Error');
         return
       }
       sent = html;
       sails.log(sent);
     });
```

The data can be accessed in the index.template.html by using the "Mustache" syntax like so {{ title }}